# Elements of a group commute if and only if the commutator is 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to prove that for $x, y \in G$, these elements commute if and only if $[x,y] = x^{-1}y^{-1}xy = 1$. What I have is:

$(\implies)$ If $x,y$ commute then $[x,y] = 1$. Because $x,y$ commute we have $xy = yx$. Then, $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy = x^{-1}xy^{-1}y = 1$.

$(\impliedby)$ If $[x,y] = 1$ then $x,y$ commute. If $[x,y] = 1$, then $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy = 1.$ Then, $(x)(x^{-1}y^{-1}xy) = (x)1 \implies y^{-1}xy = x$. Then, $(y)(y^{-1}xy) = (y)x \implies xy = yx$, which shows that $x,y$ commute. QED

I believe that is it, but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: In the $\implies$ part you seem to have used without proof that $x$ will commute with $y^{-1}$. Maybe better just play the $\impliedby$ part in reverse: $xy=yx\implies y^{-1}xy=y^{-1}yx=x\implies x^{-1}y^{-1}xy=x^{-1}x=1$.

Comment: What about shortening the proof to one line?:$$xy=yx\iff(yx)^{-1}xy=1\iff [x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy=1\;\ldots$$

Comment: @DonAntonio +1, though I was not sure if the OP wanted to see a different/better/more concise proof, or they just wanted to have *their* proof checked.

Comment: These are just what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$xy=yx[x,y]$ this may help you shorten your proof a little